# A-frame mirror the code in my div on a 2d plane

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js, aframe

### Problem

I'm creating a 3d scene using a-frame (https://aframe.io) and I need some sort of way to mirror an html div onto a plane inside a-frame. For example, lets say that there is a div with some code where I can draw on it similar a whiteboard on the bottom left corner of the screen. Everything that I draw on the whiteboard should be mirrored to the a-frame plane. That way I should be able to see my whiteboard drawing in my a-frame scene.

### What I've tried

I've tried using two components the a-frame html embed component (https://github.com/supereggbert/aframe-htmlembed-component) and the a-frame shader component (https://github.com/mayognaise/aframe-html-shader) and both work for displaying html in my scene on a 2d plane however the 2d plane in my scene doesn't mirror the whiteboard and doesn't update. That means when I draw something on my whiteboard, instead of mirroring onto 2d plane and showing what I've drawn in vr, there is just a whiteboard with nothing drawn on it.

### Problem I need solved and the ideal solution

I need to be able to create a div in html with a whiteboard or other code on it and have the same html be displayed on a 2d plane in my scene. The 2d html on the plane should update meaning if I draw the letter "a" on my whiteboard, the letter a will appear on the 2d plane in my scene. As long as there is a div where I am able to put my 2d html (my whiteboard) and the div mirrors in vr, that would be the ideal solution. Is there some code that could accomplish this?

Am I missing something with the two component I've tried that allow me to accomplish this? (Two components: https://github.com/supereggbert/aframe-htmlembed-component and https://github.com/mayognaise/aframe-html-shader) Or maybe a different A-frame component?

Ideally I am seeking the code for a component that allows me to mirror a div onto a 3d plane in my scene, or recommend a component that allows me to display **interactable** content on a 2d div.

Comment: Depending on how your whiteboard script works, maybe integrate the canvas instead of an html? https://github.com/richardanaya/aframe-canvas
  

Otherwise you could try putting an iframe into the `htmlembed` component and updating that iframe when editing the whiteboard? Could produce CORS issues though. 

  
All highly dependant on your whiteboard setup, which is not clear from the question. Sample code would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the very late answer. Here is a link to my whiteboard code: https://jsfiddle.net/AidanYoung/7421uvmq/1/

Comment: I've edited this question to slightly adjust the language around the bounty offer. While it is true that people _will_ work for fake internet points, setting demands for free labour is probably pushing the boundaries of what the bounty system is for. When a bounty is created, there are several options - amongst other things it is either to reward existing answers (not applicable here) or to get more eyeballs (what you opted for). Thus, in this case, the bounty was merely for additional exposure.

Comment: Ideally questions need not refer to their bounties at all (it is usually meta-commentary that is not useful to future readers). I'd also suggest that any wording that touches on the division of labour would be best making it clear that the question author recognises they will still be doing the bulk of the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your whiteboard uses canvas, you can make use of the [aframe canvas component](https://github.com/richardanaya/aframe-canvas).

Then at the end of your `handleUpdate()` function you want to call the component's `updateTexture()` function to update your aframe texture to the current state of the whiteboard.